# Error in loop: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, if-statement, dataframe

```
sum_temp<-c()

for (i in 1:length(Station$Day)){
  if (Station$Day[i] == Station$Day[i+1]){
    sum_temp <- sum_temp + Station$h_temp[i]
  } else 
    mean_temp <- mean(sum_temp)
# put the value in a new table but not of importance here
    sum_temp <- 0
}
```

Hi, I have a data frame containing 9 columns with "Day" as POSIXlt and several meteorological parameters as numeric. What I am trying to do in the loop is to calculate the daily mean since temperature is recorded hourly, hence each day has 24 lines. For this I ask if Day in line i is the same as in line i+1. If yes, sum up the values as long as this statement is true. If the statement is false, calculate the mean and set the sum back to 0.
However, I receive the error message "missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". Btw there is no NA in it.

Can anybody see the mistake?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Think about what is going on when you do `i +1`. If you have 10 rows/elements, it will, at one point, try to evaluate 11th row/element, which is not there.

Comment: Start with 0 instead of 1

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya R is not 0 index based. My advice would be to capture the last value and process it in a special way. There are other ways of going about this, of course, but a reproducible example would be a good start.

Comment: thanks a lot. Now I simply start with 2 and do i-1.